# What is the correct way of using @@IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server

Question regarding the `@@IDENTITY`, I have 4 different tables:

- Customer [Id]
- Person [Id, fname, lname]
- Account [Cd, owner, balance]
- Transaction [Id, account, type]

Customer Id has a feature of identity increment 1.

My goal is to create a new person for the database, so that

```
Customer.Id = Person.Id = Account.owner = Transaction.ID
```

I have tried the following below, however I get this error:

> Cannot insert null value into column owner

How do I correct the mistakes to make it work?

```
BEGIN TRAN 
    BEGIN TRY
 
      INSERT INTO bank.customer DEFAULT VALUES
      
      INSERT INTO bank.person (id, fname, lname)
      VALUES (@@IDENTITY, 'Mike', 'Phelps')

      INSERT INTO bank.account (cd, owner, balance)
      VALUES (2, @@IDENTITY, 0)

      INSERT INTO bank.transaction (id, account, type)
      VALUES (@@IDENTITY, (SELECT cd FROM pankki.tili,'P')

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

Comment: By not and using `SCOPE_IDENTITY`. Is the value of `@@IDENTITY` meant to be the same through here? Do `person` and `account` also have `IDENTITY` columns?

Comment: `@@Identity` will be NULL as you are using it. Suggest you read up on how to use [scope_identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: All the columns mentioned above should have the same identity value yes, The Person table column ID should get the value from bank.customer table which only has ID column and same goes for the account table's owner column - so everytime you create a new account its id is increased by 1 through the database.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `IDENT_CURRENT()` or `@@IDENTITY` to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Don't eat the error and convert it into a resultset. Just don't catch the error at all if you don't actually do anything useful with it - rethrow it after you rollback the transaction. BTW you missed the commit statement.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you want is this:

```sql
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN;

    DECLARE @ID int; --bigint, decimal?
    INSERT INTO bank.customer DEFAULT VALUES;
    SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); --Assumes customer has a column with an IDENTITY

    INSERT INTO bank.person (id,fname,lname)
    VALUES(@ID,'Mike','Phelps');

    INSERT INTO bank.account (cd,owner,balance)
    VALUES(2,@ID,0);

    INSERT INTO bank.transaction(id,account,type)
    SELECT @ID,
          cd,
          'P'
    FROM pankki.tili; --I assume, therefore, that pankki.tili only ever has 1 row

    COMMIT; --YOu were missing this

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK;
    THROW; --Don't SELECT the error details, THROW it.

END CATCH
```

Comment: Don't catch and rollback, just use `XACT_ABORT ON`

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft document:

> After an INSERT, SELECT INTO, or bulk copy statement is completed, @@IDENTITY contains the last identity value that is generated by the statement. If the statement did not affect any tables with identity columns, @@IDENTITY returns NULL.

I take it PERSON does not have an identity column, so when you insert into it, @@identity becomes NULL.

If you want to user the @@identity from the insert for the other tables, use it to set the value of a variable.

```
declare @PersistentID int;
INSERT INTO bank.customer DEFAULT VALUES
set @PersistentID = @@IDENTITY -- or scope_identity() is safer
INSERT INTO bank.person (id,fname,lname)
  VALUES( @PersistentID ,'Mike','Phelps')
```

Answer (score -2):

First, you need to understand the difference between this two commands:

1. `@@identity` returns the last inserted identity value in ANY table in the current session, regardless of scope.
2. `IDENT_CURRENT('table_or_view')` returns the last inserted identity value for a GIVEN table.

So, for your case, you need to use the second one.

And your script would be something like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN 
    BEGIN TRY
 
      INSERT INTO bank.customer DEFAULT VALUES
      
      SET @customerID = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('bank.customer'))
      
      INSERT INTO bank.person (id,fname,lname)
      VALUES( @customerID,'Mike','Phelps')

      INSERT INTO bank.account (cd,owner,balance)
      VALUES(2,@customerID,0)

      INSERT INTO bank.transaction(id,account,type)
      VALUES(@customerID,(SELECT cd FROM pankki.tili,'P')

END TRY
```

This way you can guarantee that the same ID in inserted in the four tables.
If you are using `@@identity` this value is changing with every new insert.

Comment: So, when 2 batches both `INSERT` into `bank.customer` at the same time, and prior to either getting the value of `IDENT_CURRENT` what do you suppose would happen here?

Comment: I think someone else needs to understand the difference, lol. `ident_current` is identical to `@@identity`. It tells you in the documentation, "The last identity value generated can be for any session and any scope."

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY` OR `IDENT_CURRENT`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Is not the same. Because the ident_current is for the specific table, but the @@identity is for all the tables. So you can't use the second one in every sentence.
But you can save the value of @@identity in a variable, and the use it for the other inserts.

Comment: This is still flawed though, @JoséIgnacioDurand . If 2 inserts happen at the same time (which they can, and do) `IDENT_CURRENT` is going to give both sessions the latest identity regardless of session, not for that session. Race conditions are a problem, and need to be handled. That's why `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is vastly better here; it can't suffer that problem.